# Why do we need to restart Tomcat every time we edit a Servlet class

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, restart

While we modify a user-defined Servlet class, we need to Restart the Apache Tomcat Server. 
but Whenever we modify a JSP file, we need NOT Restart.

Please anyone tell me the exact reason behind that..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's because Tomcat doesn't support hot code replacement. If you're developing in an IDE like Eclipse, then you could use among others the [JRebel](https://jrebel.com/software/jrebel/) plugin to achieve this. As of now (May 2019), JRebel has still no free alternatives (primarily because this is really non-trivial).

There are however servers which support hot code replacement out the box, such as [WildFly](https://wildfly.org/) and [Payara](https://payara.fish). For them JRebel is not needed when you edit *existing* methods. These servers are out the box capable of performing hot code replacement via JVM hot-swap feature. JRebel is then only needed when you want to add *new* classes/methods and get them to deploy instantly.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for your Answer.